# Как сделать тиражирование серверов?

Tags: php, linux

Всем привет. Сейчас есть много проектов, которые очень однотипны: php, apache, redis, mysql и 2 демона. На это устанавливается composer + из него Laravel.

Каждый раз заходя по ssh, приходится тратить ~1-2 часа, чтобы все установить и настроить. Какие есть самые простые способы тиражирования серверов в данном случае? Понятно, что можно и sh-скрипт написать, но это ненадежно: отвалится один модуль и полетит все остальное.

Comment: ansible? [семьсомволов]

Comment: https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh

Comment: что может отвалится если потратить те же 2 часа на тесты сценария и потом уже применять... Как я понял вы не админкой занимаетесь?

Answer (score 3):

Вечер добрый.

Все зависит от вашего опыта - это ключевое в таком вопросе.

Второе это - с какими типами сервиров работаете, какая целевая ОС? железо, ВПС, AWS, Azure и тд...

Вариант 1

*OS: GNU/Linux, Serv:  hardware, vps*

с нуля

- организуем PXE загрущочную стойку либо транслируем все по сети удалено. Формируем preseed (Debian,  Ubuntu), добовляем в конец архив со всеми конфигами которые будут развертыватся после установки. Допиливаем тонкие моменты (ssl, имя хоста, виртуальные хосты)

уже есть доступ к ОС

если нужно покрыть от 3 и более серверов с разнороднымии с схожимт настройками смотрите в сторону автоматических оркестраторов

чем пользуюсь сам (на 3-400 железок):

- Ansible (Python/YAML)
- AWX (GUI для Ansible)
- Rundeck

так же популярны:

- Puppet
- Chef
- Salt
- Terraform

У меня заготовлены полные отработанные разного типа preseeded ISO, сценарии для Ansible и с тем же результатом но в bash.

Так же не забывайте о модных нынче контейнерных технологиях. Удачи в автоматизации!

**Ссылки**

- пример развертывания рабочей станции на основе Ansible https://github.com/Hellseher/iwi

Answer (score 0):

Докер - сделал шаблон, указал там все команды для установки как в sh скрипте. Собираешь образ контейнера и можно распространять. Таким образом пропускаешь все стадии развертования - только копируешь одраз.

Также можно этот контейнер обновлять с образа.

Только папки проекта и баз данных выноси из контейнера для сохранности.

Отдельный сервис можно дополнить каким-то софтом используя наследование образов.